# python on-the-fly md5 as one reads a stream

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does python 3 have a structure for making a filtering stream? In particular, my goal here is to calculate an md5 checksum of the contents read from a REST service with requests without making an extra copy. If I could subclass some sort of filter stream and just shove the bytes into a hashlib-derived md5 object I'd be good.

Currently, my code includes:

```
shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, outstream)
```

where 'r' is the response object. Can I wrap a generator or some such thing around r.raw that will be called with each buffer of data as read, so that I can then pass it into md5?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`requests` supports [reading URL data in chunks](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests), and the `hashlib` library lets you calculate a MD5 in chunks, so you have everything you need right there already. You can choose between [`.iter_lines()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#requests.Response.iter_lines) or [`.iter_content()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#requests.Response.iter_content):

```
import requests
import hashlib

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

sig = hashlib.md5()
for line in r.iter_lines():
    sig.update(line)

print(sig.hexdigest())
```

If you *have* to view it as a filter, use a generator:

```
class MD5TransparentFilter:
    def __init__(self, source):
        self._sig = hashlib.md5()
        self._source = source

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in self._source:
            self._sig.update(line)
            yield line

    def hexdigest(self):
        return self._sig.hexdigest()
```

then use that on your `.iter_lines()` or `.iter_content()` iterator:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
filtered = MD5TransparentFilter(r.iter_content(1000))

for line in filtered:
    # do something with the line

print(filtered.hexdigest())
```

For `shutil.copyfileobj()` you'd need to implement a `.read()` interface instead of `.__iter__()`, but the principles are the same:

```
class MD5TransparentFile:
    def __init__(self, source):
        self._sig = hashlib.md5()
        self._source = source

    def read(self, buffer):
        # we ignore the buffer size, just use the `.next()` value in the source iterator
        try:
            line = self._source.next()
            self._sig.update(line)
            return line
        except StopIteration:
            return b''

    def hexdigest(self):
        return self._sig.hexdigest()
```

The `MD5TransparentFile()` class takes your `.iter_content()` or `.iter_lines()` iterator, and return data from that on each call to `.read()`, as well as calculate the MD5 on the fly. This can be used directly for your `shutil.copyfileobj()` example.