# How to calculate md5 for file in s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a requirement to calculate md5 values for files that are held in s3 buckets.  I know that I could download them to an onprem server and do it there but I want to keep my onprem server as small as possible and some of my s3 files are large (500MB+).  So I have started developing a lambda python function do handle this but I can't figure out how to chunk through the file so I can generate the md5 value.  Here is the code, I look forward to any assistance provided.

```
def s3_md5sum(bucket_name, object_key):
    try:
        md5Object = s3object.Object(bucket_name, object_key)
        body = md5Object.get()['Body'].read()
    except ClientError:
        raise
    else:
        md5_obj = hashlib.md5()
        while True:
            buffer = body.read(8096)
            if not buffer:
                break
            md5_obj.update(buffer)
        hash_code = md5_obj.hexdigest()
    md5 = str(hash_code).lower()
   
    return md5
```

Comment: For some files depending on the encryption and how the files got there the `ETag` is the md5 hash of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file as a stream instead of trying to read the entire file in memory. You can then use the hashlib library to create the MD5 based on the chuncks of the stream. An example of this can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014854/python-on-the-fly-md5-as-one-reads-a-stream).